# Do left joins preclude EF6 query plan caching?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

[This post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx#4) on EF performance considerations states that:

> The Skip(), Take(), Contains() and DefautIfEmpty() LINQ operators do
>   not produce SQL queries with parameters but instead put the values
>   passed to them as constants. Because of this, queries that might
>   otherwise be identical end up polluting the query plan cache, both on
>   the EF stack and on the database server, and do not get reutilized
>   unless the same constants are used in a subsequent query execution.

I primarily use `DefaultIfEmpty` as a means of getting EF to generate LEFT JOIN queries. Does this mean that any query containing a manual LEFT JOIN (EF will also generate LEFT JOINs for some navigation property usages) using DefaultIfEmpty() won't benefit from caching? Is there any workaround?

Comment: `...unless the same constants are used in a subsequent query execution.`,  I suspect you are using the same constants in your queries.

Comment: @RobertMcKee good call. I didn't read this carefully enough. I guess I'll have to keep digging to discover why my query isn't caching! If you put this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: You do realize the query plan cache just caches the plan and not the results, correct?  How are you determining that the query plan isn't being cached?

Comment: @RobertMcKee yes I realize this. I can tell whether it is being cached by using DbInterception to time the difference between my executing the LINQ query and the DbCommand being ready. With caching, this is usually a few milliseconds. Without caching, it can be up to 3 seconds for a particular query in our system